# "Триггер" на подключение Bluetooth наушников в Windows

Tags: windows, bluetooth, headset

Я пользуюсь китайскими, немного проблемными, `Bluetooth` наушниками фирмы `Bluedio`. И у меня есть проблема с подключением их к `Windows`-ноутбукам. 
При включении они подключатся в режиме `"Voice only"` (работает только микрофон) с максимальной громкостью, если после этого сделать `Disconnect`, а потом `Connect` - то все ок, `"Voice and Music"` и я могу слушать музыку.
(Настройками в `Windows` поправить не смогла - думаю, проблема в самих наушниках)

Хочу сделать костыль: написать некий скрипт, который при подключении наушников по `Bluetooth` будет автоматически делать `Disconnect -> Connect`. И уменьшать громкость до заданного уровня.

Никогда подобным не занималась, подскажите, пожалуйста, позволяет ли `Windows` подобную "кастомизацию"? В какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: Можно поискать на autoit как это делать

Comment: Скриптом не получится, придется покодить немного.

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, почитаю.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko, я готова кодить :) Интересует, в основном, на чем писать и что позволить реализовать задачу.

Comment: Писать можно на чем удобно. А задача решается парой вызовов функции BluetoothSetServiceState, которая, собственно, позволяет удалить драйвера для Bluetooth устройства и установить их обратно.